# is it possible to do text wrapping ALL AROUND an element?

Tags: css, word-wrap

**Is it possible to style text wrapping ALL AROUND an element as it appears in the image attached? (Either CSS, or JQuery)**

[image: Wrapping of Text All Around Image]
.

Thank you

Comment: No. And from a design perspective that is just terrible.

Comment: Not with CSS, not sure if there is a way with jQuery.

Comment: @Bryan Naegele Why is terrible?

Comment: @IberoMedia: Why is it terrible? Just try reading your sample text aloud. It's a strain on the eye and on the brain to keep jumping across the image and back.

Comment: It's just poor graphic design.  It's extremely hard on the reader to read your text.  Text should never be difficult to read.

Comment: @BryanNaegele - It doesn't matter whether you like it or not. The answer however is, yes you can do this. I have not done it but I've seen it done and without any slicing. Unfortunately, I can't write up an example right now.

Comment: @Rob: I think pointing out that it would be a bad idea is a valid part of an answer. It's something I'd want to know if I were asking a question of how to do something - perhaps it would help me come up with an alternative design that solves my original problem a different way. I'd be interested in your solution if you have time to post it later, but only from a "proof of concept" point of view; I still wouldn't use it in a web page, nor recommend that anyone did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's only an ugly hack where you cut your image into "slices" and have them sitting inside your paragraph text at the right spots. Needless to say, that's not very nice nor very dynamic.

Floating only allows you to move elements to the left or right.